# How to write [String] to text file in Swift?

Tags: swift

I create an array in swift like so:

```
var imagesArray = [String]()
```

and I add some base64 images to that array like so:

```
imagesArray.append(imageBase64String!)
```

Now I need to create a text.txt file and write the `imagesArray` into that file so I can send it to the server.

I tried this:

```
let fileName = "myFile.txt"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let data = Data(imagesArray)
do {
    try data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
    print(url)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But this produces this error:

```
No exact matches in call to initializer
```

which is infant of this code: `let data = Data(imagesArray)`

could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in initializer for `Data` that takes in a `[String]`. `imagesArray` is a `[String]`, so it doesn't work.

How do you want to save the array of Strings? If you want a new line between each String, you can try something like this (no need to use `Data`, instead, combine the array into 1 string):

```
let fileName = "myFile.txt"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let joinedImagesArray = imagesArray.joined(separator: "\n") /// separated by newline
do {
    try joinedImagesArray.write(toFile: url.path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    print(url)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: the code you've provided throws a few errors!

Comment: This works with no error: try joinedStrings.write(toFile: outputURL.path, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

Comment: @rooz far glad you figured it out! I didn’t test my answer, should have.

Comment: iOS 10+ you can simply use `FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory`. Btw there is also a URL version of the write method. `write(to: url, ...`